# Customize Chromium for a smaller tab/address bar?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, chromium

I've got a 1024x600 display on my laptop that, while large enough for most of my activities (I'm running a pretty heavily customized XMonad setup) is cramped for web browsing. I've done a lot to make Chromium render the web smaller -- smaller fonts, reduced default image scaling, etc.

The thing I want to do now is to make the Chromium top bar itself smaller. I'm running it without close/minimize buttons or borders, so the only waste of space is in the large size of the tab bar and address bar (and neighboring back/fwd/refresh and tools/extensions buttons). Fullscreen mode doesn't work under my WM setup, and even if it did, I'd still like access to a tab bar of some kind. Is there a way to make the fonts that the Tab bar and the Address bar use smaller or scale the entire interface down some?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I've tagged this as Chrome as well, since they're so similar and might have similar solutions to this problem. I hope that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Chrome does not (yet?) include a built-in (read easy, practical) way to alter the actual shape or size of the interface elements. [Themes](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/themes.html) only allow you to set textures and colors, which is why if you look at [available themes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes?hl=en), they all have the same sizes and shapes.

I would imagine that there are others who have [asked about it](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), but if so, I cannot seem to filter out the relevant issues (though chances are good that they have been unceremoniously closed anyway).